# Square Mobile Web API for Android gives "Unsupported API Version" What is the correct version number for the current API?

Tags: android, square, pos

We are trying to support the Square Mobile Web API to process a charge from a mobile web POS system.  The API seems to be straightforward as documented by Square (https://developer.squareup.com/docs/pos-api/web-technical-reference).  The sample code uses S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0 and we've tried that and other higher numbers but always get:

> Unsupported API Version - The installed version of Square is too old.
> It doesn't support this version of the Point of Sale SDK.

We are running the latest version of the Square App (5.56.1).  We have also tried version numbers in the format of v2.0-2020-12-16.

I've distilled this down to a single link as a sample.  Does anyone know what the correct version parameter should be or see anything else wrong?  Thanks!

```
<A HREF="intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;S.com.squareup.pos.REQUEST_METADATA=341;S.com.squareup.pos.LOCATION_ID=...;package=com.squareup;S.browser_fallback_url=https://.../takeorder/install;S.com.squareup.register.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=https://.../takeorder/square;S.com.squareup.register.CLIENT_ID=....;S.com.squareup.register.API_VERSION=V2.0;i.com.squareup.register.TOTAL_AMOUNT=1;S.com.squareup.register.CURRENCY_CODE=USD;S.com.squareup.register.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.register.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.register.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE,com.squareup.register.TENDER_CASH,com.squareup.register.TENDER_OTHER;end">
```

Comment: Might be case sensitive? In the example code it's a lowercase `v`, but in your code you have an uppercase `V`. Try lowering it?

Comment: Thanks...we have tried that.